# Issue while sorting Combo Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I'm working on a task in which I need to populate the comboBox through List and the List is populating from `employee.dat` file. I'm successfully populates the combo but while sorting it I'm facing an issue. The Values which I'm trying to sort is String Numbers. It shows the values from 0-9 but when it beyond from 9 the combo looks goofy.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

What I need to do is sort these values, Means 10 should be leading by 9.

Here is the code snippet which I have tried yet.

```
         private void FormDelete_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //LOAD EVENT for FORM

        //Clear all form controls
        Reset();

        //Fill the ID Combo box using data in List<T>
        comboBoxID.Items.Clear();
        foreach (MyClass.Employee obj in MyClass.listEmployees)
        {
            comboBoxID.Items.Add(obj.ID);
        }

        //Sort the combo box ibn ascending order
        comboBoxID.Sorted = true;

    }
```

**Employee.cs**

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID;
        public string fName;
        public string lName;
        public string gender;
        public int age;
        public double hourWage;

    }
    public static List<Employee> listEmployees = new List<Employee>();
```

**Empolyee.dat**

```
1, Ann, Crowe, F, 34, 12.95
2, Bob, Costas Jr., M, 27, 8.75
3, Sue, Soppala, F, 22, 7.95
4, Bill, Barton, M, 45, 15.25
5, Jill, Jordan, F, 33, 14.75
6, Art, Ayers, M, 33, 14.75
7, Larry, Stooge, M, 55, 21.05
8, Art, Ayers, M, 33, 14.75
9, Larry, Stooge, M, 55, 21.05
10, Art, Ayers, M, 33, 14.75
11, Larry, Stooge, M, 55, 21.05
```

**List Populating code**

```
 if (File.Exists("employee.data"))
        {
            try
            {
            streamEmployee = new StreamReader("employee.data");  
            string line;  //to read a line from the text file
            string[] arrFields = new string[5];
            while (streamEmployee.Peek() > -1)
            {
                line = streamEmployee.ReadLine();  //read a line of records      from file
                arrFields = line.Split(',');  //split the line at comma junction, and save split                            //fields in array 

                MyClass.Employee objEmp = new MyClass.Employee();  //create a "specific" employee                                       //object instance

                //Assign each field from line as generic object's properties to make it "specific
                objEmp.ID = Convert.ToInt32(arrFields[0].Trim());  //ID is integer
                objEmp.fName = arrFields[1].Trim();
                objEmp.lName = arrFields[2].Trim();
                objEmp.gender = arrFields[3].Trim();
                objEmp.age = Convert.ToInt32(arrFields[4].Trim());  //age is integer
                objEmp.hourWage = Convert.ToDouble(arrFields[5].Trim());  //hourly wage is double

                //Add this specific employee object to the List
                MyClass.listEmployees.Add(objEmp);

            } //while


        } //try

        catch (IOException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            error = true;

        } //catch

        finally
        {
            if (streamEmployee != null)  //it is indeed representing a file and may not be closed
                streamEmployee.Close();


        } //finally

    } //if
```

Comment: Your file is already sorted, if you remove the Sorted=True line you have already the items in the right order

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your response I have tried this and it works. But what if I change the order from my input source file? comment out the sorted line is not the solution.

Comment: Just added an answer specifically for this case

Answer (score 3):

Your file is already sorted, thus there is no need to call Sorted=true.
Anyway, if you want to be sure that, whatever order is present in the input file, your code adds the employees following the ID order, then you could change your loop to

```
foreach (MyClass.Employee obj in MyClass.listEmployees.OrderBy(x => x.ID))
{
    comboBoxID.Items.Add(obj.ID);
}
```

Again no need to set the Sorted property to true....

Comment: As best practice do not depend on the sorting order of the input file. Reason is, if input file sort order changed, you combo box behavior will change. Make sure to handle it by you code.